# How do I close/hide/shut down my Jframe/class using a button in java?

Tags: java, swing

Right so I have a simple .setVisible(true); to navigate to other pages but I want to be able to hide stuff in some sections, close the whole program in some sections such as "cancel button" to close the whole program.
I tried the same thing but instead (false); and it didn't work
please show me how to do this thank you, I would like to do this without changing my current code because it will confuse the hell out of me and im new to programming.
Here is my code I'm using GUI builder.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


/**
* This code was edited or generated using CloudGarden's Jigloo
* SWT/Swing GUI Builder, which is free for non-commercial
* use. If Jigloo is being used commercially (ie, by a corporation,
* company or business for any purpose whatever) then you
* should purchase a license for each developer using Jigloo.
* Please visit www.cloudgarden.com for details.
* Use of Jigloo implies acceptance of these licensing terms.
* A COMMERCIAL LICENSE HAS NOT BEEN PURCHASED FOR
* THIS MACHINE, SO JIGLOO OR THIS CODE CANNOT BE USED
* LEGALLY FOR ANY CORPORATE OR COMMERCIAL PURPOSE.
*/
public class MainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JLabel username;
    private JLabel passwordlbl;
    private JLabel Welco;
    private JPasswordField Passwordfld;
    private JButton Cancelbtn;
    private JButton OKbtn;
    private JTextField Usernametxt;
    private String Password = "pass";

    /**
    * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //PASSWORD field to store new password inside
        //Passwordfld.setEchoChar('*');
        //Passwordfld.addActionListener(new AL());

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainMenu inst = new MainMenu();
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public MainMenu() {
        super();
        initGUI();
    }
    private static boolean isPasswordCorrect(char[] input) {
        boolean isCorrect = true;
        char[] correctPassword = { 'b', 'u', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'o', 'o' };

        if (input.length != correctPassword.length) {
            isCorrect = false;
        } else {
            isCorrect = Arrays.equals (input, correctPassword);
        }

        //Zero out the password.
        Arrays.fill(correctPassword,'0');

        return isCorrect;
    }
    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);

            username = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(username);
            username.setText("User Name:");
            username.setBounds(63, 113, 80, 16);

            passwordlbl = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(passwordlbl);
            passwordlbl.setText("Password:");
            passwordlbl.setBounds(63, 160, 72, 16);

            Usernametxt = new JTextField();
            getContentPane().add(Usernametxt);
            Usernametxt.setBounds(198, 110, 79, 23);

            final JPasswordField Passwordfld = new JPasswordField();
            // Passwordfld.setText("Secret");
            getContentPane().add(Passwordfld);
            Passwordfld.setBounds(198, 157, 79, 23);
            Passwordfld.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // System.out.println("Passwordfld.actionPerformed, event="+evt);
                // TODO add your code for Passwordfld.actionPerformed
            }
            });
            OKbtn = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(OKbtn);
            OKbtn.setText("OK");
            OKbtn.setBounds(102, 217, 59, 23);
            OKbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                String passText = new String(Passwordfld.getPassword());

                String cmd = evt.getActionCommand();

                if (OKbtn.getActionCommand().equals(cmd)) { // Process the password.
                    if (Usernametxt.getText().equals("Admin")&& (isPasswordCorrect(passText.toCharArray()))) {

                        System.out.println("Password Accepted");

                        ItemsPage ItemsPage = new ItemsPage();
                        ItemsPage.setVisible(true);
                    } else {
                    System.out.println("Password Rejected: " + passText);

                    }

                    // Zero out the possible password, for security.
                    Arrays.fill(passText.toCharArray(), '0');

                    Passwordfld.selectAll();

                    /*
                     * else{ System.out.println("permition Rejected"); }
                     */

                    // else{}
                    /*
                     * if (Passwordfld = Password)= true) {
                     * System.out.println("permition granted");}
                     */
                }

            }
            });

            Cancelbtn = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(Cancelbtn);
            Cancelbtn.setText("Exit");
            Cancelbtn.setBounds(198, 217, 61, 23);
            Cancelbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                    //System.out.println("Cancelbtn.actionPerformed, event="+evt);
                    //TODO add your code for Cancelbtn.actionPerformed
                }
            });

            Welco = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(Welco);
            Welco.setText("Welcome to Jstore please log in using your staff acount");
            Welco.setBounds(51, 19, 291, 16);





            pack();
            setSize(400, 300);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //add your error handling code here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    //static class AL implements ActionListener{
    //JPasswordField input = new JPasswordField();

    /*  char [] passy = input.getPassword();
        String p = new String (passy);{
        if (p.equals (Password)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct"); }
            else
            {       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "InCorrect");

        }
        */


}
```

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with a upper case character!!! If you want to close the frame you can use `frame.dispose()`.

Comment: Yeah I know. It's a bad habit I've worked with other programming languages. Do you recommend I change them? and I tried the dispose, doesn't work :(

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a Swing builder. It makes things like these so much harder.

Comment: I can't now :'( I've done my whole application like this and there's LOTS and lots of code, I would be even happy with hiding Jframe or even making it so once a new jframe pops up you can't click the one at the back or something like that.

Comment: `Do you recommend I change them?` - yes, if you want people to answer your questions and read your code. Look at how the variables are highlighted differently in your posted code. The variables with the upper case character are incorrectly highlighted which makes the code hard to read. `I tried the dispose, doesn't work` - post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: So just the first of the letter? the rest won't matter if it's uppercase?

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.exit()` to shut down an entire program. `Frame.dispose()`will destroy your JFrame, and finally, `Frame.setVisable(false)` will hide your frame, but not destroy it.

So, to answer your question literally, it would be `Frame.dispose()`/`Frame.setVisable(false)`/`System.exit()`

Comment: "The method exit(int) in the type System is not applicable for the arguments ()", FRAM.DISPOSE = "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method dispose() from the type Window"

Comment: 1. Use `System.exit(0)` to indicate a successful shutdown to the OS. 2. Use your instance of the class, not the class itself. Intead of `FrameClass.dispose()`, use `MyFrameInstance.dispose()`.

Comment: frame.dispose() will also exit the JVM if this is the last frame.

Comment: Guy I'm trying all these techniques you're telling me in my button action listener, I'm really confused I have no idea what you're saying I'm pretty new to java do you mind kindly emending your example based on my code or kindly show me? this is driving me nuts, sorry to bother or trouble you and I appreciate you being patient with me.

Comment: By JVM he means the thing running your program. You should read a Swing tutorial before you do this. You can safely ignore his last comment for now.